# How to open and run an individual playgroundpage

Tags: xcode

This is probably already answered on here (I haven't found it yet, but, please, point me in the right direction) but I thought I'd ask anyways. How do you open individual .xcplaygroundpage's without
A) opening the whole .xcworkspace or
B) making a whole new .xcworkspace and adding the .xcplaygroundpage to it.
I am using Xcode 8.3.2